# What is the purpose of the extra chair is Shampoodle's?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Shampoodle's in "Animal Crossing: New Leaf," Shampoodle's has an extra seat next to the one you sit in. What is it for?

Comment: I'm gonna guess it's just decoration.  Like the shopping trolleys in T&T Mart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Decoration**.

A lot of the shops in New Leaf have a whole lot of decoration, and this is no exception. The parlor would look quite empty with only one chair. The chair does in fact **not do anything** in the game mechanically.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do anything. The Shampoodle shop wouldn't look good with one chair. Your character can sit on it but Harriette will not style your character's hair when sitting on that chair.